# Does SDL SmartTarget = SDL Fredhopper?

Tags: tridion, fredhopper

Not directly an implementation question but hopefully someone can offer a few pointers.

I wanted to ask if by integrating SDL SmartTarget into Tridion you are effectively getting SDL Fredhopper as well?

Do you still get Fredhopper Business Manager etc?

Could you feed more traditional product data straight into Fredhopper, outside of Tridion then build a site with personalisation/targeting via SmartTarget mixed with a product catalogue driven by Fredhopper and all the cross-sell/up-sell/recommendations it can do?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, SDL SmartTarget includes SDL Fredhopper, and you can indeed add data to it via the Data Manager.

The main differences between both offerings is obviously the connector and Ambient Data Framework support for ST queries, a set of Java Taglibs/.NET controls you can use to communicate with Fredhopper and a few other things like session preview support for FH queries (ability to change the variables on-the-fly for testing).

N

Comment: Thanks Nuno. So I'm looking at building an ecommerce site, content managed by Tridion but inc. ST for personalised content. We still want cross-sell/up-sell/recommendations for products and there's no PIM. Should I be looking at putting product data into Tridion, then into FH via ST or just straight into FH? I know this is very generalised, but FH seems perfectly aligned to a product-catalog style site, but ST seems to muddy things a little.

Comment: I don't want to muddy the waters further, but there might be a licensing consideration to this. It's not my area, and I don't know the details for this client, but someone is looking in to it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Jeremy

Comment: FH will not be a PIM, so you'd need to find a solution for that part anyway. The good news is that if you're using Tridion-as-a-PIM (with all its known limitations) then you will not run into licensing considerations with ST - the content is coming from Tridion and potentially "enriched" with Data Manager, rather than coming from a 3rd party tool altogether.

Comment: So with Tridion-as-a-PIM, the cross-sell/upsell of related products could be handled in ST through its triggers rather than FH campaigns?

Comment: Not sure I get the question - FH Campaigns are still available with ST, but indeed using triggers is what I see the most.

Comment: Perhaps I need to organise a demo of FH with SDL! Basically we want the targeting/personalisation of ST for marketing content and the product cross-sell/upsell/recommendations of FH for our product data. In a Tridion-as-a-PIM scenario, can both these requirements be satisfied by ST?

Comment: @Niel It is possible to mix Tridion content and product data in 1 FH system, although there are some limitations depending on how you want to store it.

Comment: @Nuno The session preview support (on the fly changing) is not ST specific but works solely on the Ambient Data Framework.

Comment: Thanks Gertjan. Are you able to elaborate on the limitations? Feel free to email me direct rather than clog the answer if you prefer.